# Admin can't create items for self with CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan, cancancan

I'm using `CanCanCan` for authorization. An admin can manage all, so they don't have per-user-id rules. The result is that they can't create items for self by default. It looks like I need to add a bunch of extra plumbing to make `create` in my controllers work the same for admins as it does for general users. The reason seems to be `Ability#attributes_for` doesn't provide the admin user with the user_id attribute.

How are other people getting around this? Are you writing code to specifically handle the admin use case in your view or controller?

Relevant parts of the Ability class

```
if user.admin?
  can manage, :all
else
  can manage, Purchase, user_id: user.id
end
```

Example interaction

```
2.6.2 :012 > Ability.new(User.find(3)).attributes_for(:create, Purchase)
 => {:user_id=>3}
2.6.2 :013 > Ability.new(User.find(4)).attributes_for(:create, Purchase)
 => {}
```

User 3 is general_user, User 4 is an admin

In the controller

```
# relying on load_and_authorize_resource
def create
  puts @purchase.user_id # => nil for admin, 3 for general user
  # have to add this for admin use case
  @purchase.user = current_user
  ...
end
```

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to achieve? An Admin can CRUD anything right, or do you want to limit their abilities?

Comment: Hmm, I see your controller code now... I don't think you should use this approach. CanCanCan Abilities are for defining access rights, not for assigning user ID's. Let me quickly write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on the Ability object to assign user_ids to your new objects. I think it's better to explicitly write it in the controller. It seems more clear what's happening. So basically just initiate a new object in the create method and don't rely on `load_and_auhtorize_resource`

```
def create
  @purchase = current_user.purchases.new(purchase_attributes)
end
```

If the user wasn't authorized, CanCanCan would already have interfered.

ps. I have been a CanCanCan user for years, but recently moved to Pundit. I think the way it was designed is way better and clearer than CanCanCan. Check it out if you have the time!

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and the plug for pundit.

Comment: For the record: I've got nothing against CanCanCan and no strings with Pundit... just a tip as a fellow RoR dev :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in CanCanCan. Defining the ability `can(:manage)` needs an id. Creating a record doesn't. So the ability file doesn't allow you to create bc it's looking only for record that it can find with an id. if you define `can :create, Purchase` above where you define the `:manage` you should be good :D

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :create, Purchase
  can :manage, Purchase, user_id: user.id
end
```

Comment: This answer really helped me to understand why i had `cannot?(:create, class, *args) => false` and `cannot?(:create, class_instance, *args) => true` at the same time.